# Retrofit an interface to an existing C++ class without using "forwarder" methods

Tags: c++

This is a C++ question but let me start by illustrating what I am trying to achieve. In C# I can write the following:

```
interface IPermissions
{
   bool CanView( );
   bool CanUpdate( );
   bool CanDelete( );
}

class Concrete
{
   public bool CanView( ) { return true; }
   public bool CanUpdate( ) { return true; }
   public bool CanDelete( ) { return true; }
}

class Record : Concrete, IPermissions
{
}
```

and doing so will allow me to do this:

```
IPermissions record = new Record( );

record.CanView( );
```

In essence I have "retrofitted" an interface against an existing class, without changing the base class. I guess that technically I have retrofitted the interface using a new derived class, but the key point is more about how straightforward it is.

I recently had a need to do a similar thing in C++ and I cannot work out how to do this elegantly. I can do it inelegantly using a bunch of forwarder functions like so:

```
class IPermissions
{
   public:
   virtual bool CanView( ) = 0;
   virtual bool CanUpdate( ) = 0;
   virtual bool CanView( ) = 0;
};

class Concrete
{
   public:
   bool CanView( ) { return true; }
   bool CanUpdate( ) { return true; }
   bool CanDelete( ) { return true; }
};

class Record : public Concrete, public IPermissions
{
   public:
   bool CanView( ) override { return Concrete::CanView( ); }
   bool CanUpdate( ) override { return Concrete::CanUpdate( ); }
   bool CanDelete( ) override { return Concrete::CanDelete( ); }
};
```

An obvious response is to say modify the Concrete class to derive from IPermissions, but for this example it is not feasible (eg. not my code).

I tried in-class using statements (more hoping they'd work rather than expecting they'd work) but they don't help the situation.

Is there a pattern or idiom that can help overcome this issue, without the solution becoming so complex that it obfuscates the original intent?

Comment: Re: the comment “don't like virtuals implemented this way” — they’re not virtual.

Comment: In C++ you nornally derive Concrete from "interface". But that's not exact analog of what is going on in C# or Java (those languages essentially created a short-cut for what C++ had). You may want to use a "mix-in" or CRTP, depending on what constraints are